# Does this sequence of a maximal cyclic subgroup of an abelian group split?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A$ is a finite abelian group, does the exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow G \rightarrow A \rightarrow A/G \rightarrow 0$$
split if $G$ is a maximal cyclic subgroup (i.e., no if $G \leq H \leq A$ and $H$ is cyclic, then $G=H$)? I've tried playing with the proof of the classification of finite abelian groups, but I don't see how to turn the proof I know of the classification into a proof of this. http://www.isama.org/jms/m317/handouts/finabel.pdf proves this for abelian $p$-groups, but I don't see how to extend the proof in general. If someone has a counterexample, that would also be appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't this follow from the $p$-group case since every finite abelian group is a direct product of its $p$-Sylow subgroups?

Comment: @GregMartin Unless I missed something, I couldn't see how to prove this from the p-group case because my cyclic subgroup $G$ might not be contained in any Sylow subgroup.

Comment: @MichaelBarz It doesn't have to be. Just decompose all groups (also $G$) into their $p$-primary parts.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry, would you mind posting this as an answer? I don't see how to conclude.